# MSXML with Visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, msxml

Is there a good tutorial to read/write XML? I have been scouting all over the Internet, but found nothing about MSXML.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I learnt from the [MSDN articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759192%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), on it and the smattering of code on [CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/misc/misc/article.php/c3707) and [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/msxmlcpp.aspx).