# Read and write xml document from mfc dialog application

Tags: c++, xml, mfc, msxml

How to read and write xml files in mfc dialog based application. I'm using visual studio 2012. When I searched for some articles I got to know to import msxml6.dll file. But it's showing error in my IDE Visual studio 2012. So plese help me out, I'm new to this technology. thank you.....

Answer (score 2):

You can use any xml parser you want: msxml, Xerces, tinyxml, or any of the 100's of others you can find by googling.

To find out how to use msxml, search this site or google and you will find posts such as this: [MSXML with Visual c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417345/msxml-with-visual-c) .